pybind11: how to add document the exported module?
I have some c++ code, and I successfully export it to python module using pybind11. The code is:
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {

    }

    /**
    * @brief explanation from c++
    */
    int GetWidth()
    {
        return width; 
    }

private:
    int width = 0; 
};


PYBIND11_MODULE(module, m) {


    m.doc() = "My Library Python Bindings";

    py::class_<A>(m, "A")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("GetWidth", &A::GetWidth, "explanation from pybind");

}

My question is: how to read the documentation for function in pycharm?
For example, when I use opencv, I can know the input for function. For example:

But, when I import my-self module, I don't know what is the input parameter.
For pybind11, how can I add the documentation for the exported module?
In addition, I add lots of explanation for c++ function using the doxygen format. Is it possible to convert the c++ explanation to python function.
Any suggestion is appreciated~~~

you need to create a stub file, see What is the use of stub files (.pyi ) in python?.
a stub file just contains the definition of the function, for example here is the definition of the opencv function you are looking at in its stub file. __init__.pyi
@_typing.overload
def imread(filename: str, dst: cv2.typing.MatLike | None = ..., flags: int = ...) -> cv2.typing.MatLike: ...

the function body is an ellipsis ... you can also add a docstring in there.
pycharm can generate some stub files for extensions (with limitations) but the portable way is to provide your own stub file.
